# Get a value from a promise function in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have the following in a `utilityfunction.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
 grabValue: function() {
  var params = {
    apiVersion: 'v1',
    endpoint: "https://localhost:8200",
    token: "MY_TOKEN"
  };

  var vault = require("node-vault")(params);
  vault.read('secret/mysecret/foo').then(v => {
     var myvalue = result.data.value;
     resolve(myvalue);
  }).catch(e => console.error(e));
 }
};
```

Then in another file called `use.js` , I import `utilityfunction.js` like so:

```
var rUtil = require('./utilityfunction.js'); 
var getMyValue = rUtil.grabValue();
```

This return an `undefined` value for `getMyValue`.

I basically want to return the value from my `grabValue` function.

Answer (score 1):

You should return result of `vault.read` call. Another bug is that, you call undefined `resolve` function, I guess you tried to create a `Promise` with constructor and leave it:

```
module.exports = {
  grabValue: function() {
    ...

    var vault = require("node-vault")(params);
    return vault.read('secret/mysecret/foo')
      .then(v => {
        var myvalue = result.data.value;
        return myvalue;
      })
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
  }
};
```

So as `grabValue` is async function, you can't get result immediately, you need to use `then` callback:

```
var rUtil = require('./utilityfunction.js'); 
rUtil
  .grabValue()
  .then(myValue => console.log(myValue));
```

Answer (score 1):

Promises are basicaly a constructor with a `.then`and `.catch` property each taking a function as first parameter. When the Promise resolves it calls the function you passed as parameter to the `.then`, if the Promise reject, it calls the one you passed as parameter to the `.catch`.

That being said, when you want to retrieve the value resolved by a Promise, you will get it as the first parameter to your function you passed to the `.then`.

Example:

```
// let's start a promise
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     // let's resolve a promise
     resolve('foo');
})
.then(result => {
     // if our promise is resolved, it will call the function here
     // result argument is the value passed to the resolution
     console.log(result); // foo
});
```

So in your case grabValue should be rewritten :

```
grabValue: function() {
  var params = {
    apiVersion: 'v1',
    endpoint: "https://localhost:8200",
    token: "MY_TOKEN"
  };

  var vault = require("node-vault")(params);
  return vault.read('secret/mysecret/foo')
  .then(v => {
     return v;
  })
  .catch(console.error);
 }
```

And then when calling grabValue :

```
grabValue()
.then(result => {
    console.log(result); // result is v
    // continue your logic here
});
```

A Promise will never return anything else that iself. **So you CANNOT do something like that :**

```
const a = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return resolve('foo');
});

// here a will be a Promise and the only way to access 'foo'
// is to call the `.then` this way :

a.then((result) => {
    // result = 'foo'
});
```

Note that when inside a Promise chain (meaning inside the `.then` or `.catch`callbacks), if you are doing async calls you must return a Promise to make sure the next `.then` will wait for that async call to be done, but if you are not doing an async call, you can just return a value and it will be the first argument of your callback. If an error is thrown while in a Promise chain, it will be caught in the `.catch` callback.

Example:

```
const somePromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     return resolve();
})
.then(() => {
    // i'm doing some async
    // so i return a Promise
    // the next .then will be called only when my promise is resolved
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         resolve('foo');   
    });
})
.then((result) => {
    // I'm not doing any async i can just return the value
    return result + 'bar';
});

// then I can get the value from somePromise
somePromise.then((result) => {
     console.log(result); // foobar
     // I'm in a Promise chain and an error occurs
     throw new Error('Oups something went wrong');
})
.catch((err) => {
   console.log(err.message); // Oups something went wrong
});
```

Comment: @francoispqt - Excellent explanation, thank you. 

Two questions - 

1. Why do I need to perform a return on vault.read('secret/mysecret/foo')? According to your explanation, surely I only care about returning the resolve d Promise from inside the .then block?

2. I want to be able to assign the resolved value to a variable but it's not quite working

`var myValue = rUtils.grabValue().then(result => {result});`

I think this returns an actual Promise object.

Comment: Actually, you have to return the `vault.read('secret/mysecret/foo')` because it also returns a Promise. By doing `var myValue = rUtils.grabValue().then(result => {result});` myValue will be a Promise object, if you want to have the result you would have to do `myValue.then(result => {  })`

Comment: Sorry just so I am clear:
`var myValue = rUtils.grabValue().then(result => {result});
var getValue = myValue.then(result => { });`

Is that correct?

Comment: No, a Promise will never return anything else than a Promise. You need to continue inside the `.then(result => { /* do something here */ })`.

Comment: To get the value from a Promise, you must always use `.then(result => {})`

Comment: Really sorry, quite confused now. Have tried lots of different things to try to assign the value to a variable. 

E.g. tried `var myValue = rUtils.grabValue().then(result => {returnPass = result.data.value; return returnPass;});`

Comment: A Promise does not return anything else that itself. You have to continue your logic from the `.then`, the same way you would do with a callback style async call.

Comment: I've added a short paragraph to my answer, we can move to a chat if you want.